# In react bootstrap, how do I increment a counter within a push?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm getting a warning, saying that each child in a list should have a unique key.  So I decided to set up a counter, and then assign it to each key.
Here is my initialization:

```
function App() {
  const [keyCount, setKeyCount] = useState(1);
```

Then I add the key:

```
tempComp.push(<p key={setKeyCount(keyCount+1)}><b>{dResult[y].dp5}</b></p>);
```

But the key isn't adding 1 like I thought it would.  How do I increment the keyCount each time?

** For clarification:
I'm actually displaying the fields on different lines.  So I need something else besides index to use.
On line 94:

```
tempComp.push(<p key={dResult[y].index}><b>{dResult[y].dp5}</b></p>);
```

On line 97:

```
tempComp.push(<p key={dResult[y].index}>1D{dResult[y].dp2}={tempRoll}</p>);
```

That's why I was trying to use a counter, because the warning is telling me that each key must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

When rendering list items in React, you can use `index` as a key for your items:

`const list = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple']`

```
function Fruits() {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((fruit, index) => <div key="index">{fruit}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's a good practice if you only need to render items without doing actions like editing or deleting items from the list. Otherwise, it can affect app performance.

Comment: I think you meant to use {index} rather than "index", but otherwise good answer!

Comment: This may work in another example, but in mine I am separating my lines and formatting them differently, so I need to use something other then index as the key.  That's why I was trying to increment, but it wasn't incrementing correctly.